# Summernote: .summernote with ('code') removes initialization options

Tags: javascript, image-uploading, summernote

I initialize summernote as:

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
            height: ($(window).height() - 300),
            callbacks: {
                onImageUpload: function (image) {
                    alert("image");

                }
            }
        });
```

When I call the function

```
lastAppendedObj.find("textarea[name='html1']").summernote("code", value.html1);
```

on a textarea with the name html1, for that textarea, onImageUplaod function is not overwritten anymore. What might be the cause for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you call .summernote("code",anything), It will override the current summernote with the default one.

If you want summernote with the defined options just take the above parameters in json and pass the same. For Example:

```
var testJson={
            height: ($(window).height() - 300),
            callbacks: {
                onImageUpload: function (image) {
                    alert("image");

                }
            }
        }

$('.summernote').summernote(testJson);

lastAppendedObj.find("textarea[name='html1']").summernote(testJson, value.html1);
```

Comment: It doesn't populate